# Is there a better way to write read and modify text lines and write them into an output stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

I'm currently trying to read a file, modify a few placeholders within and then write the file into an output stream. As its the output stream for a page response in aspx.net I'm using the OutputStream.Write method there (the file is an attachment in the end).

Originally I had:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    while (readBytes < fs.Length)
    {
        tmpReadBytes = fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        if (tmpReadBytes > 0)
        {
            readBytes += tmpReadBytes;
            page.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, tmpReadBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

After thinking things over I came up with the following:

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
   string modifiedLine = line.Replace("#PlaceHolder#", "NewValue");      
   byte[] modifiedByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(modifiedLine);    
   page.Response.OutputStream.Write(modifiedByteArray, 0, modifiedByteArray.length);
}
```

But it looks inefficient especially with the conversions. So my question is: Is there any better way of doing this?

*As note the file itself is not very big, it's an about 3-4 KB sized textfile.*

Comment: Why are you reading bytes instead of text if what you have is text?

Comment: What's wrong with `Response.WriteLine(modifiedLine);`?

Comment: @Albireo The original code wasn't from me (I took over that project). I would guess it is because back then he used .Write for the OutputStream that he didn't want to convert the bytes read and thus used the FileStream .Read method and read bytes instead of the text)

Comment: Well, then nuke the whole snippet from orbit and replace it with `File.ReadAllText` and you're good.

Comment: @Luaan I did not see any WriteLine method for  the HttpResponse class?   Write(String) I saw and WriteFile . Would Write(String) be what you meant? (searched the whole time in the outputstream class instead of httpresponse so didn't see those methods so far)

Comment: @Albireo then it would be File.ReadAllText  and page.Response.Write(modifiedString) ?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that's a sane thing to do only if you *know* the file you're reading will always be small. Otherwise, use a `StreamReader` and read in chunks (lines?).

Comment: In this case the file itself is custom made by me and the 4 KB already did take considerable growth into account (I would see the max. at 2.5KB anyway).   thanks a lot! (will remind myself next time to look not only in the property but also in the mainclass if there can be any appropriate method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to handle the bytes your self.

If you know the file is and always will be small,

```
this.Response.Write(File.ReadAllText("path").Replace("old", "new"));
```

otherwise

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (streamReader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            this.Response.Write(streamReader.ReadLine().Replace("old", "new"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the later method how you currently wrote it would only read and write a single line in total?

Comment: Can happen to even the best :)  Accepted your answer there. tnx again there!

Answer (score 0):

To get the lines in a string array:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
```

To alter the lines, use a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("#PlaceHolder#", "NewValue");
}
```

And to save the new text, first create a string with all the lines.

```
string output = "";
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    output+="\n"+line;
}
```

And then save the string to the file.

File.WriteAllText(file,output);